# Can i refresh Chat history in Teams #Bot framework

Tags: .net-core, botframework, microsoft-teams

Is there any way to refresh/clear **BOT** chat history and start new conversation in MS Teams.
If Yes please let me know how to do it .

Comment: Do you mean clear bot chat history using graph api?

Comment: i want to clear bot chat history in teams .Is that available through graph api ?If yes please share the link or give some information how to do it .thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is (as of the posting of this answer) no way to delete teams chat history, so there is no way to clear the previous messages of a bot from the teams client. There are ways to clear a bot's conversation state, but as the bot's Microsoft app ID is tied to a Teams app ID as soon as you add the channel, the messages displayed on the teams chat window are there to stay no matter how you handle your bot's state/history storage.

The only work around for this is to remove the bot from Teams entirely, and redeploy it using a new Bot Channels Registration/Web App bot, which doesn't, per se, **delete** the history so much as create a totally new bot.

For reference:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/delete-a-chat-in-teams-da6d87ed-59bc-4407-9291-95ee193f8344

Comment: can we like end the conversation after a period of like 5 minutes of inactivity and when a new activity is detected, the bot sends a welcome message or restarts the conversation?

Comment: I too have the same question. Any luck?